# How can I insert an image with an id to a RichTextBox in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, image, richtextbox

I just came across a problem with `RichTextBox` in .NET.

Using [Insert Plain Text and Images into RichTextBox at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R)
  I can insert an image to the `RichTextBox`. Then what I want is that when the image in the `RichTextBox` is clicked, a MessageBox pops-up showing its name or id.

My question is: how can I embed the name or id of the image into the rtf of the `RichTextBox`?

I have tried to add parameters into the rtf string using:
`{\pict{\pictName myName}{\pictID myID}\wmetafile8...}` and then set to `richtextbox1.Rtf`;
but I found that there are still no parameters in

```
 richtextbox1.Rtf:{\pict\wmetafile8...}
```

Is there any other way, except comparing the whole WmfBits to the list in the background, to get the image's name or id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you managed?